# How to prove this $T(n) = 5n^2\log _2n+n -8 = O(n^2) $

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How to prove if following is true or not? I seem to have some deep rooted problems with logarithms.

$$T(n) = 5n^2 \log _2n+n -8 = O(n^2) $$

I have been thinking something like this:
$5n^2 \log _2n+n -8\leq c_1n² $ and dividing both sides with $n²$ but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Except that $T(n)$ is not $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the two functions $T(n)$ and $n^2$ in a ratio and examine it as $n\to\infty$:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^2\log_2n+n-8}{n^2} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n^2\log_2n}{n^2}+\frac{n-8}{n^2}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}5\log_2n+\frac{n-8}{n^2}
\end{align}$$

This limit is infinite because of the logarithm, so we have that $T(n)$ grows faster than $O(n^2)$. If we had found a finite limit, we would have shown the desired result.